# Pull data from service on an interval and display in the notification center

Tags: ios, objective-c

Is it possible to have an iOS app pull the data from a service, let's say `www.mysite.com/iphone/notifications`, that would produce JSON like (below is just an example could be anything really):

```
[
    {
        "Message":"Notification 1",
        "Detail":"Notification 1 detail"
    },
    {
        "Message":"Notification 1",
        "Detail":"Notification 1 detail"
    }   
]
```

The app would then go ahead and register some sort of background worker and pull the notifications every x minutes.

Is this concept possible or do I need to go trough the `Apple Push Notification Service`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is what Apple calls "Background Fetch".

Your app will get notified when iOS calls your delegate's `performFetchWithCompletionHandler` method. It's then up to you to call your service and do something with the new information. You could create a local notification at this point.

It's not (publicly) defined how often iOS will call your delegate method, but it seems to increase the more the app is used, how quickly your app finishes its work, and if it accurately reports whether new data was downloaded or not.

Link to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

> **Fetching Small Amounts of Content Opportunistically**
>
> Apps that need to check for new content periodically can ask the system to wake them up so that they can initiate a fetch operation for that content. To support this mode, enable the Background fetch option from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project. (You can also enable this support by including the UIBackgroundModes key with the fetch value in your app’s Info.plist file.) Enabling this mode is not a guarantee that the system will give your app any time to perform background fetches. The system must balance your app’s need to fetch content with the needs of other apps and the system itself. After assessing that information, the system gives time to apps when there are good opportunities to do so.
>
> When a good opportunity arises, the system wakes or launches your app into the background and calls the app delegate’s application:performFetchWithCompletionHandler: method. Use that method to check for new content and initiate a download operation if content is available. As soon as you finish downloading the new content, you must execute the provided completion handler block, passing a result that indicates whether content was available. Executing this block tells the system that it can move your app back to the suspended state and evaluate its power usage. Apps that download small amounts of content quickly, and accurately reflect when they had content available to download, are more likely to receive execution time in the future than apps that take a long time to download their content or that claim content was available but then do not download anything.